# SOAP response status code 500

Tags: objective-c, soap, response, http-status-codes

I've tried to connect to a SOAP API from a iOS application in objective c, xcode. First, i used a wsdl2objc to produce endpoint stubs for the access, but i got response status code 500 like this:

> { URL: http://api.tradera.com/v3/PublicService.asmx } { status code: 500, headers {
>       "Cache-Control" = private;
>       "Content-Length" = 509;
>       "Content-Type" = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8";
>       Date = "Thu, 24 Mar 2016 17:36:24 GMT";
>       Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
>       "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
>       "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
>   } }

Now i have written my own SOAP request and that gives the same response. Is it the server's or my fault?

THIS is how i do it:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.tradera.com/v3/PublicService.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString* messageLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",soapMessage.length];

[request addValue:@"api.tradera.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
[request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:messageLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request addValue:@"http://api.tradera.com/GetSearchResultAdvanced" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLResponse* response;
NSError* error;
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

if ([((NSHTTPURLResponse*)response) statusCode] != 200) {
    [ErrorService alertResponseFault:((NSHTTPURLResponse*)response)];
}
```

Comment: Can you provide anymore context? Generally, `500` means internal server error which means it's the server's fault. But it could be possible that the server doesn't handle malformed requests properly and instead of sending a `400 bad request`, it freaks out with a `500`, which would mean your request is wrong

Comment: I'm not sure what else is relevant. I use the exact sample request given as example on their website, but no luck. They have a separate SOAP 1.2 version which i also have tried. It's just depressing when simple things don't work, especially if i may not causing it.

Comment: Have you tried testing it in a client like SOAPUI?

Comment: Just tested with SOAPUI and it worked fine with that. Tried to copy the exact same request to my project, but failed with same response.

Comment: Now it works! Don't know what was wrong. Probably error in request body, which I somehow dragged with me in all my tests, very stupid. Thank you for SOAPUI Chris, that helped me finally get on right track.

Comment: Glad you got it working! No problem, tools like soapui are super useful for debugging networking problems that Xcode doesn't give as much detail about

Comment: hi @user2908112, I am getting the same error in my project. Can you please help me?